# How to hide page links from theme menu

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I'm working on a plugin, I programatically create some pages in posts table,
the links appear in the theme menu(front end), I don't want some of these
page links to appear, how do I do this?

Comment: If you use `wp_nav_menu` then you can make use of `exclude` key in the arguments array.

Comment: Thanks, can my plugin modify wp_nav_menu since I wont have direct access to whatever theme users install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of users use [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to output the menu in a theme, then you could make use of the callback function that is passed in the arguments array.

`wp_nav_menu( array( 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu' ) );`

`wp_page_menu` is the default value for the callback function.

Looking further, [wp_page_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu) has an `exclude` key in its arguments array.

`wp_page_menu( array( 'exclude' => '' ) );`

You can add a filter to it by adding comma separated values to the `exclude` key in the arguments array.

```
function my_cb_function( $args ) {
  $args['exclude'] .= '10,20,30' // comma separated IDs
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'my_cb_function', 999, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Have to look for a way to get page ID's from slug.